# Git Hooks: post-merge/pre-commit/post-commit not starting after manual branch merge

Tags: git, version-control, merge, githooks

I want to create a git hook that would do some tasks after manual merge feature branch to master. I have created post-merge/pre-commit/post-commit files, but none of them starts after running commands:

```
git merge FEATURE
```

or

```
git merge FEATURE -m "FEATURE" --commit --no-ff
```

pre-commit/post-commit is working after running git commit. Where could be a problem?

Comment: Are the files executable? Are they in the right place (.git/hooks/) ? Can you run them manually?

Comment: Yes, everything is working. If I make a commit - pre-commit and post-commit hooks are working. But if I make a merge - nothing happens.